# Configure Monolog to send GELF via TCP in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, graylog, gelf

I have the following configuration in my monolog.yaml file:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: "php://stdout"
            level: debug
            channels: ["!event"]
        gelf:
            type: gelf
            publisher:
                hostname: mygelfhost.com
                port: 12201
        console:
            type: console
            process_psr_3_messages: false
            channels: ["!event", "!doctrine", "!console"]
```

But it only sends messages to mygelfhost.com using UDP. When I tried to put:

```
hostname: tcp://mygelfhost.com
```

I receive the following error:

```
  Failed to create socket-client for udp://tcp://log-dev.hpa.lis-dev.net:12201: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0)
```

My goal is to send the logs via TCP to the same host, I have checked the configuration here: https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L25 with no possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of @Chase's answer:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        gelf:
            type: gelf
            publisher: my_tcp_gelf_publisher
```

The difference above is my_tcp_gelf_publisher is a Publisher object, not a Handler object. You want to tell the handler, which publisher to use "my_tcp_gelf_publisher", since that's what's being defined in services.yaml

In services.yaml:

```
services:
    my_tcp_gelf_publisher:
        class: Gelf\Publisher
        arguments: ["@gelf.tcp_transport"]
    gelf.tcp_transport:
        class: Gelf\Transport\TcpTransport
        arguments:
            - "mygelfhost.com" # Hostname
            - 12201 #port
```

This is pretty much the same, except you'll need to put the @gelf.tcp_transport service reference in quotes, otherwise you'll get a scaler error.

A bonus tip, if by chance you decide to configure your transport to use port 12202 (Gelf\Transport\TcpTransport's SSL port) be sure to ensure your endpoint supports ssl and you provide the correctly configured SslOptions object, otherwise use standard port 12201 (or any other port).

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the transport for Gelf. By default it uses UDP.

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        gelf:
            type: gelf
            id: my_tcp_gelf_publisher
```

In your services:

```
services:
    my_tcp_gelf_publisher:
        class: Gelf\Publisher
        arguments: [@gelf.tcp_transport]
    gelf.tcp_transport:
        class: Gelf\Transport\TcpTransport
        arguments:
            - "mygelfhost.com" # Hostname
            - 12201 #port
```

Something like this should work, I havent tested the code though. Based on the defining a publisher and the config example from: https://github.com/bzikarsky/gelf-php